# Local time on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time, nstimer

I need to display the exact local time and the time should be running.

Please help, if possible with sample code or explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This returns the current date with Time

```
[NSDate date];
```

Now you can use NStimer to fetch the time every one second and display it.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(displayTime) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
//Time Interval is one second
-(void) displayTime
{

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss a";
    NSString *dateString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate: currentDate];
    yourlabel.text = dateString;
    [timeFormatter release]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it worked well, i have one more question how to display the time with AM/PM. Please help!

Comment: timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss a";